# C# TMP102 on Raspberry Pi. Crazy Temps Returned

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, i2c

I'm trying to use a TMP102 I bought from Sparkfun.com with my Raspberry Pi.

I'm using Mono on the Pi and copied the code from this [site](http://bradsrpi.blogspot.com/2014/07/c-mono-code-to-read-tmp102-i2c.html) to get a jump.

Here's what I have:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace NDBC_Keg_Manager
{
    public class Tmp102
    {
        private string i2cgetExe = "/usr/sbin/i2cget";
        private string i2cgetCmdArgs = "-y 1 0x48 0 b";

        private Process p;

        public Tmp102()
        {
            p = new Process();
        }

        public double tempC
        {
            get { return readRawTempData(); }
        }
        public double tempF
        {
            get { return this.tempC * 1.8 + 32; }
        }

        private int readRawTempData()
        {
            // Don't raise event when process exits
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            // We're using an executable not document, so UseShellExecute false
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Redirect StandardError
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            // Redirect StandardOutput so we can capture it
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            // i2cgetExe has full path to executable
            // Need full path because UseShellExecute is false

            p.StartInfo.FileName = i2cgetExe;
            // Pass arguments as a single string
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = i2cgetCmdArgs;
            // Now run i2cget & wait for it to finish
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            // Data returned in format 0xa017
            // Last 2 digits are actually most significant byte (MSB)
            // 2 digits right after 0x are really least significant byte (LSB)
            string data = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            // Get LSB & parse as integer
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Raw Hex: " + data.ToString());
            data = data.Substring(4, 2);
            int hexData = Int32.Parse(data, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);
            Console.WriteLine("Pre-Dec: " + data.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Dec: " + hexData.ToString());

            return hexData;

        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            Tmp102 t = new Tmp102();
            while (true)
            {
                // Print temp in degrees C and F to console
                Console.WriteLine("{0}°C  {1}°F", t.tempC, t.tempF);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I get on the Raspberry Pi is a temp of 119c on one sensor and 90c on the other.  The fact that two sensors are both so out of whack is what led me to ask if its the code that's wrong in some way??

The original code had the reading of two bytes and flipping them due to i2cget reversing to output and shifting 12bit to a dec value.   The documents from TI say that the MSB is the whole temp.  I get that value directly by using the b flag instead of the w flag with i2cget on the Pi.

Suggestions??

Comment: Is 0xA017 exactly 119 degrees? I'm getting 122 going by the docs on the chip here.

Comment: A017 was in the comments. Actual value received in my office is: 0x7B or 123c.

Comment: That's quite a toasty office you've got there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From section 7.3.1 in the [documentation](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tmp102.pdf) for that chip:

> Byte 1 is the most significant byte (MSB), followed by byte 2, the least significant byte
>   (LSB). The first **12 bits** (13 bits in extended mode) are used to indicate temperature. The least significant byte
>   does not have to be read if that information is not needed. The data format for temperature is summarized in
>   Table 2 and Table 3. One LSB equals **0.0625°C**. Negative numbers are represented in binary twos-complement
>   format ... Bit
>   D0 of byte 2 indicates normal mode (EM bit = 0) or extended mode (EM bit = 1) , and can be used to distinguish
>   between the two temperature register data formats.

So, it seems that the bytes need to be swapped, and you need to strip out the other bits containing other information. Then you need to scale by 0.0625. Something like this should do the trick:

```
ushort raw = 0xA017;
int swapped = ( ( raw & 0x00FF ) << 8 ) | ( raw >> 8 );
int trimmed = swapped & 0xFFF; // 12 bits
double temperature = trimmed * 0.0625; // 122.0
```

This works for positive temperatures. For negative, see the instructions on page 8 of the manual.

Comment: I added your code and bypassed the orginal final bit shifting...  I still get 122 deg C.  I guess maybe that both TMP102 Breakouts are bad..?  Hard to believe that.  I'll call Sparkfun about it.

Comment: Hmm, that seems a bit unlikely. I did check the code against some of the samples on page 9 in the manual, seems to be working. Maybe you could double-check that. And perhaps there's some initialization that needs to be done before reading? Haven't read the full doc.

Comment: The raw bytes returned was 0x9777.  This manifested as 121.4375 per your code, and 119 deg C with my original code (after edits).  Two methods same result. (Roughly.  Lower presiscion with using the single byte MSB method vs MSB and LSB together).  I don't need to be that accurate.

Comment: That's strange. Swapping 0x9777 to 0x7797 and trimming to 12 bits gives 0x0797. The closest value to this in the manual's example table is 0x07FF == 128 degrees, so 121/119 does seem to be correct.

Comment: Ok.  I got out an old Arduino and plugged in one of the many ready to go TMP102 sketches.   Worked liked a champ.  Something with the Pi is wrong.  I'll mark this as the answer as it works.  Just not with my Pi correctly.  Thanks.

Comment: Something must be funky with the I2C there I guess.